# Qui: Pronom relatif ou subordonnant?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, subordonnées

On compte dans les classes de mots les catégories suivantes:

1. Nom
2. Déterminant
3. Adjectif qualificatif
4. Pronom
5. Verbe
6. Adverbe
7. Préposition
8. Conjonction
9. Interjection

Il existe plusieurs types de pronom, dont le pronom relatif. Dans la phrase suivante:

> J’aime Les Lilas **qui** sont blancs.

« Qui » est un pronom relatif avec « lilas » comme antécédent.

Un subordonnant est la même chose qu’une conjonction de subordination. Dans l’exemple donné, « qui » introduit une proposition relative, c’est donc un subordonnant. Or un subordonnant est une sous-catégorie de la classe de mots de conjonctions avec les coordonnants (conjonctions de coordination).

À quelle catégorie appartient « qui » alors? C’est considéré comme un pronom ou comme une conjonction de subordination?

Answer (score 2):

C'est un pronom relatif et pas une conjonction de subordination.

Pour le démontrer, on peut regarder n'importe quel dictionnaire ; seules deux fonctions existent pour le mot « qui » : pronom relatif et pronom interrogatif.

Il ne faut pas être influencé par « que » qui lui peut en fait fonctionner comme conjonction de subordination (exemple : *je dis que tu manges* vs *la pomme que tu manges*). « Qui » n'est jamais classé comme conjonction de subordination même s'il introduit une proposition subordonnée. Il est à noter que même si on remplaçait la proposition par un équivalent utilisant « que » (exemple: *J'aime les lilas que tu m'as apportés.*), « que » fonctionne comme pronom relatif (c.o.d. d'« apporter ») et non comme conjonction de subordination.

La raison pour laquelle ce n'est pas une conjonction est qu'il remplace un nom, ce qui est la fonction du pronom. Dans ta phrase, « qui » remplace « lilas » et fonctionne comme sujet de la proposition relative (ce qui est par définition une proposition subordonnée introduite par un pronom relatif ; elle ne nécessite donc pas une conjonction de subordination).